# How to negate disadvantage on performance?

Tags: dnd-5e, bard, advantage-and-disadvantage

My bard will need to play for a long time. Long long time. Long enough that they'll basically collapse from exhaustion, as the purpose is to show devotion. *Forced march* rules seem to fit, so we can assume my DM will use an approximation of those, with CON+3 giving total exhausted play time of 8-12 hours (feel free to do exact maths) to reach exhaustion level 5 (speed 0). I assume I will need to roll performance at least once per exhaustion level. I would very much like to do that without disadvantage on performance.

My Valor bard will be level 10, and utilizing level 10 Magical Secrets is an option. This is a one-time event. My bard has relevant instrument proficiency, if that can help. Solution can be, but does not have to be, somehow getting advantage for all these rolls. Getting a specific magic item might not be out of the question. Multi-classing is not an option. Having allies provide help through the entire marathon performance would not fit RP-wise. It would be acceptable to negate disadvantage only on *some* of the exhausted performance rolls, if that is easier to achieve.

(Ask for more details and I'll add them here.)

In this situation, what ways exist to negate the disadvantage caused by exhaustion level 1 on *Performance(CHA)* ability checks?

Comment: Is this a solo performance or are you permitting assistance from allies?

Comment: You should explicitly state that *they must collapse and so reducing exhaustion is not the solution*.

Comment: I don't think this is answerable, since "how to get advantage on an ability check" is generally up to your DM.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Using *Greater Restoration* or *Potion of Vitality* to prolong the show might still be good bonus, thanks for the idea!

Comment: @MarkWells That's not my question though. It might be an answer, if only way to negate the disadvantage is to "figure out something situational which you could use to persuade your DM to give advantage". If that's as good as it gets, then that'd be a valid answer.

Comment: Voting to re-open, as I think the question now describes in-game situation clearly enough, and there also is a decent answer fitting the details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Time to Get Splendid

This is actually easier than you might have expected. You'll need to rely upon the spell *Enhance Ability* to cover you for this. This is an often overlooked spell because it's impacts on combat aren't usually as significant as they were in 3.5 plus it eats up precious Concentration.

Assuming you're using the rules for a Forced March, your first 8 hours of playing will be without Disadvantage to begin with, but after that point your fingers are going to be bleeding a bit and it's important to look good. So you'll be casting *Enhance Ability* and choose the *Eagle's Splendor* version to give yourself Advantage on your Charisma checks, which Perform falls under. This spell can be maintained for a maximum of 1 hour, so it should be sufficient to cover the entire time until your next check for Exhaustion.

Given that you're a 10th level Bard, you'll be able to cast and re-cast this spell up to 11 times, which should be more than enough to get you through your full performance before you faceplant (majestically) into the floor from Exhaustion.

Comment: This seems superb fit, and a spell I'll want to have anyway!

Comment: I would note that it is possible that the DM will ask for concentration checks to maintain the spell under the considerable pressure.

Comment: @Szega we at Pyrotechnical Answer Industries cannot be held liable for additional saves requested by your DM. Always check with your cleric before electing to play 3 Phish songs in a row.

Comment: @Szega That's possible, though it would be a precedent for exhaustion to make all concentration spells very difficult. Another thing I'll need to verify before taking this spell is, wether the DM will consider spell concentration to interfere with musical performance in general.

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir Well, asking for concentration saves in harsh conditions is RAW, concentration interfering with anything else is not... so if your DM rules so, it will be a house rule. One I would advise against, but that is another issue.

Comment: @Szega Checking the RAW, it would take *environmental phenomena* (or damage) to require concentration check, and I don't think playing until the exhausted qualifies in the RAW, assuming comfortable indoor environment with no other unusual distractions.